# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Parent instance <User at 0x197950dead0> is not bound to a Session;

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Hey I am trying to print all stocks which users have

```
class User(Base, TableNameMixin):
    user_id: int = Column(BIGINT, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    stocks: Mapped[List["Stock"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")

class Stock(Base, TableNameMixin):
    stock_id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id: int = Column(BIGINT, ForeignKey("users.user_id"))
    symbol: str = Column(String(10), nullable=True)
    quantity: int = Column(Integer, server_default=text("34"))
    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="stocks", foreign_keys=[user_id])

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Stock(symbol={self.symbol}, quantity={self.quantity})>"
```

This is how I defined my db model
This is my function to add stock to user

```
async def select_user(user_id: int) -> Optional[User]:
    async with async_session() as session:
        select_stmt = select(User).where(User.user_id == user_id)
        result = await session.execute(select_stmt)
        user = result.scalar_one_or_none()
        if user.stocks:
           print("yes")
      
        except Exception as e:
            await message.answer(str(e))
```

Please correct if i am doing something wrong.

**Full error**
`Parent instance <User at 0x2277a012190> is not bound to a Session; lazy load operation of attribute 'stocks' cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/bhk3)`

Comment: I can't reproduce this even after fixing the invalid syntax.. Please provide a [mre]